# Return respective answer based on multiple choice

Tags: jquery, html

Edited the code to show just the 1 question.

When I click an answer. the div returned should match the answer clicked.
So 1 will return answer1, 2 answer 2 .. At the moment they all return answer 1.

```
 function clear_delay(timeoutID_here) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutID_here);
}
/* Run 1 */
function run_loading_run_1(time_delay) {
    timeoutID1 = window.setTimeout(run_loading_1, time_delay);
}

function run_loading_1() {
    $('.thank_for_close, .run_loading_2').fadeIn();
    $('.main_review').hide();
}
/* Run 2 */
function run_loading_run_2(time_delay) {
    timeoutID2 = window.setTimeout(run_loading_2, time_delay);
}

function run_loading_2() {
    $('.thank_for_close, .run_loading_2').hide();
    $('.run_loading_3, .li_run_loading_1, .li_run_loading_2').fadeIn();
}
/* Run 3 */
function run_loading_run_3(time_delay) {
    timeoutID3 = window.setTimeout(run_loading_3, time_delay);
}

function run_loading_3() {
    $('.run_loading_3').hide();
    $('.run_loading_4, .li_run_loading_3').fadeIn();
}
/* Run 4 */
function run_loading_run_4(time_delay) {
    timeoutID3 = window.setTimeout(run_loading_4, time_delay);
}

function run_loading_4() {
    $('.run_loading_4, .loading').hide();
    $('.li_run_loading_4, li_run_loading_5, .run_loading_5, .show_end').fadeIn();
}
$(".step3 a").click(function () {
    $('.content').hide();
});
$(function () {
    $('.next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
    });
    $('.a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
        $('.run_loading').hide();
        $('.step4a .loading').show();
        run_loading_run_1('700');
        run_loading_run_2('1500');
        run_loading_run_3('2200');
        run_loading_run_4('3500');

    });
    $('.b').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
        $('.run_loading').hide();
        $('.step4b .loading').show();
        run_loading_run_1('700');
        run_loading_run_2('1500');
        run_loading_run_3('2200');
        run_loading_run_4('3500');

    });
    $('.c').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().hide().next().fadeIn();
        $('.run_loading').hide();
        $('.step4c .loading').show();
        run_loading_run_1('700');
        run_loading_run_2('1500');
        run_loading_run_3('2200');
        run_loading_run_4('3500');

    });
});
```

My html is

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="step3 marker_show">
         <h2>Question 3: <span>these are different</span></h2>
<a href="#" class="step_button step_button_1 run_loading a">1</a>

        <br /> <a href="#" class="step_button step_button_2 run_loading b">2</a>

        <br /> <a href="#" class="step_button step_button_3 run_loading c">3</a>

        <br />
    </div>
    <!-- STEP 3 END -->
    <div class="step4a marker_show" style="display:none;">
         <h3 class="run_loading_1 main_review">Reviewing your answers</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_2" style="display:none;">question1.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_3" style="display:none;">Artice Count.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_4" style="display:none;">Your Selected Tags.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_5" style="display:none;">Congratulations!</h3>

        <center>
            <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" class="loading" style="display:none;">
        </center>
        <ul class="done_marker">
            <li class="thank_for_close" style="display:none;">Access Allowed</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_1" style="display:none;">Logging in</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_2" style="display:none;">Answer to question3 is 1</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_3" style="display:none;">Please Wait...</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_4" style="display:none;">Get Access Below!</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="show_end" style="display:none;">
             <h4>Searching For Best Deal</h4>
 <a id="agree" href="link1" class="step_button step_button_1 agree">CLICK HERE NOW »</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- STEP 4A END -->
    <div class="step4b marker_show" style="display:none;">
         <h3 class="run_loading_1 main_review">Reviewing your answers</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_2" style="display:none;">question1.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_3" style="display:none;">Artice Count.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_4" style="display:none;">Your Selected Tags.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_5" style="display:none;">Congratulations!</h3>

        <center>
            <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" class="loading" style="display:none;">
        </center>
        <ul class="done_marker">
            <li class="thank_for_close" style="display:none;">Access Allowed</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_1" style="display:none;">Logging in</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_2" style="display:none;">Answer to question3 is 2</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_3" style="display:none;">Please Wait...</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_4" style="display:none;">Get Access Below!</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="show_end" style="display:none;">
             <h4>Searching For Best Deal</h4>
 <a id="agree" href="link2" class="step_button step_button_1 agree">CLICK HERE NOW »</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- STEP 4B END -->
    <div class="step4c marker_show" style="display:none;">
         <h3 class="run_loading_1 main_review">Reviewing your answers</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_2" style="display:none;">question1.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_3" style="display:none;">Artice Count.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_4" style="display:none;">Your Selected Tags.. check</h3>

         <h3 class="run_loading_5" style="display:none;">Congratulations!</h3>

        <center>
            <img src="images/loading.gif" alt="" class="loading" style="display:none;">
        </center>
        <ul class="done_marker">
            <li class="thank_for_close" style="display:none;">Access Allowed</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_1" style="display:none;">Logging in</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_2" style="display:none;">Answer to question3 is 3</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_3" style="display:none;">Please Wait...</li>
            <li class="li_run_loading_4" style="display:none;">Get Access Below!</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="show_end" style="display:none;">
             <h4>Searching For Best Deal</h4>
 <a id="agree" href="link3" class="step_button step_button_1 agree">CLICK HERE NOW »</a> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- STEP 4C END -->
</div>
```

I have put it up here http://jsfiddle.net/GWq4V/2/

Comment: Can you distill the problem down to a smaller less complicated amount of js and html?  I feel like I can't quite figure out what the problem is based on the js fiddle and your question.

Comment: You've hard coded <li class="li_run_loading_2" style="display:none;">Answer to question3 is 1</li> in your html. You neither have the options for other answers in your HTML nor you're modifying the existing one dynamically. Then how do you expect to get a different result..?! And by the way you don't need thousand different functions to do similar things... this is really not how you do it.. please read some js tutorials regarding functions, what are arguments, how to pass values to a function, how to change content dynamically etc a proper answer for this Q would mean doing from the scratch..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simpler problem to solve and perhaps it could help you do whatever it is you are trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/bUJPL/

JS:

```
var answers = ['first answer', 'second answer', 'third answer'];

$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
    var answerIndex = $(this).attr('data-answerindex'),
        answer = answers[Number(answerIndex, 10)];

    $($(this)).after('<span class="answer">'+answer+'</span>');
    $(this).hide();

});
```

HTML:

```
<button data-answerindex="0">Button 1</button>
<button data-answerindex="1">Button 2</button>
<button data-answerindex="2">Button 3</button>
```